# Beginner python error: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python

I know there's other posts with a similar title to this, but I still cannot find a solution to this issue after countless attempts (I'm new to Python). Whenever I try to run `pipenv install`, I get this error:

```
bash: /home/nick/.local/bin/pipenv: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

However, the `/usr/bin/python3` directory does not exist (although python2.7 & python3.7 do), so I assume if it tried to use the python3.7 path then it may work. Why is this error occurring, and how can I change whatever it is so that it uses a correct directory? I don't know how to explain this issue any other way.

Also, I have installed pipenv already (running `pip install pipenv` or `pip3 install pipenv` both show as already installed).

Here's some outputs when running the following:

- `python --version` returns `Python 3.7.3`
- `python V` returns `Python 3.7.3`
- `echo $PATH` returns `/home/nick/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin`
- `which bash` returns `/bin/bash`
- `pipenv --version` returns `bash: /home/nick/.local/bin/pipenv: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`
- `pip --version` & `pip3 --version` both return `pip 21.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)`
- `python -m pip --version` returns `pip 21.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)`
- `sudo apt install python3-pip` shows as already installed

Note that I'm running this on my Raspberry Pi 3b. Thanks for any help here.

Comment: What OS are you using? Rasbian?

Comment: yeah it is Raspbian.